# Bulk insert from a txt file which has its own rules

Tags: bulkinsert, text-files, bulk

I got a txt file which includes 350.000 lines and I have to download and insert it to my sql server database. I write the part that connects to FTP  gets the related file and download it. What I want is insert it to my table.

Here's a line:
9996281000L0000000000000000

As you can see also I need to seperate the specific parts like
999 628 1000 L 0000000000000000

I need an effective solution which cuts the lines and inserts the data to related columns.

Anyone any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: What language, platform, database?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the BCP utility and its format files. It's a detailed and somewhat complex process, but it will do the job quickly and efficiently once set up.

You can get similar functionality (with a much better GUI) with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). While completely different, it does much the same thing as bcp.